# Turn Off HtmlEncode on KendoUI AutoComplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a MVC Kendo UI AutoComplete control that I am binding to json data that contains HTML.

View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
.Name("MyAutoComplete")
.DataTextField("Text")
.Template("${  data.Text  }")
.DataSource(ds => ds.Read( read => read.Action("GetAutoCompleteItems", "Home"))
    .ServerFiltering(true)
 )
.MinLength(3))
```

Controller:

```
    public JsonResult GetAutoCompleteItems(string text)
    {
        var response = new List<SelectListItem>();

        response.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="<strong>My Html</strong> Text", Value="1"});

        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I can see that the control is encoding the template here:

```
'var o,e=kendo.htmlEncode;with(data){o=''+()+'=e(  data.Text  )';;o+='';}return o;'
```

Is it possible to turn this off?  I just want to highlight the text that matches my search string.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how exactly you would do it in MVC Kendo UI. But in general with a template like `#= data.Text#` it would work.